# Freeing loaded texture on WebGL

Tags: webgl

The Textured Box demo on http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Demo_Repository has the following code snippets:

```
function loadImageTexture(ctx, url)
{
    var texture = ctx.createTexture(); // allocate texture
    texture.image = new Image();
    texture.image.onload = function() 
                              { doLoadImageTexture(ctx, texture.image, texture) }
    texture.image.src = url;
    return texture;
}

function doLoadImageTexture(ctx, image, texture)
{
    ctx.bindTexture(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    ctx.texImage2D(ctx.TEXTURE_2D, 0, ctx.RGBA, ctx.RGBA, ctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);  // loaded the image
...
}
...

var spiritTexture = loadImageTexture(gl, "resources/spirit.jpg");
...
```

How do you free the allocated/loaded texture in order to avoid (graphics) memory leak?

Will the following code free both the loaded/allocated texture and image?

```
spiritTexture  = null;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

NOTE: Cross post on http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=3367 on December 23, 2010 but no answer so far.

Comment: +1 just for the honest (old) cross-post exposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ctx.deleteTexture(spiritTexture);
```

That should free the texture on the gpu.

Regarding the image, you should just modify `loadImageTexture` so that it doesn't store `image` inside `texture`.  The reference to `image` is not needed outside `loadImageTexture` and you can let it go out of scope naturally when `doLoadImageTexture` completes.

i.e. make it something like:

```
function loadImageTexture(ctx, url)
{
    var texture = ctx.createTexture(); // allocate texture
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() { doLoadImageTexture(ctx, image, texture) }
    image.src = url;
    return texture;
}
```